# Accelerating observers in special relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

In Hobson's General Relativity [book](https://www.mobt3ath.com/uplode/book/book-48251.pdf), pg. 125, it says that an instantaneous rest frame $S'$ can be defined for an accelerating observer in frame $S$ such that the observer is *momentarily* at rest in $S'$.

It also says

> since the observer is at rest in $S'$, the timelike basis vector $\textbf{e}'_0 $ of this frame must be parallel to the 4-velocity $\textbf{u}$ of the observer.

Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at the accelerated frame from an inertial frame K, you can always find an inertial frame S' whose velocity matches with the velocity of the accelerated frame at that instant. So in that instant the relative velocity between S' and S is zero. But it's only for that instant because S is accelerating and in the next instant it's velocity would be different.

Edit: I forgot to respond to that quoted part. For a stationary object the four velocity is (c,0,0,0) or if you're working in units with c=1, (1,0,0,0).

Answer (score 1):

The other answer has noted that the frames are *momentarily* comoving, since $S$ is accelerating and $S'$ is an inertial frame. At any subsequent moment $S$ will have accelerated slightly and will no longer be comoving with $S'$.

Regarding the part you've quoted, even in the rest frame of an object its 4-velocity is *non-zero* (ie. it is *not* the zero vector). In the rest frame of an object its 4-velocity is parallel to the $x_0$ basis vector, $\mathbf e_0'$, and so: $$\mathbf u=\mathbf e'_0.$$